# copy a existing cpp file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is a very basic question:
I just want to copy a existing cpp file into a new empty project.

I create a new `empty project` `Test`, then add a `existing item` `Main` from other folder, but the address of `Main` is still the original address and we can not see the `Main` under the `Test` folder. Even I copy the `Main` into the `Test` folder, the `Source file` can still not see the `Main` in the visual studio.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up windows explorer.  Manually copy the file to the project folder.  Then add that existing copy to the project.

Comment: it works, but I can not understand that why can't we add the cpp files directly from other folder?

Comment: @A.Oreo Copying file and adding the file into the project are two distinct physical steps. It's just that the designers of Visual Studio decide to not put these two steps under one single button. You will have to ask Microsoft if you really want to find out why.

Comment: @NickyC But if I want to copy the whole project with a lot of folders, should I manually copy and add them folder by folder? How can I copy the files among different folders into the new project?

Comment: In short, adding existing files/folders to a C++ project via Visual Studio's interface merely means you are adding a *reference*, not a copy.    If you want to copy an entire project with many folders then yes, you must manually copy them via Windows explorer first.  Also keep in mind that the "folders" you see in Visual Studio within projects are often not physical disk folders at all but merely "filters" -- a way of organizing them within the VIsual Studio UI.

Comment: @Joe Yeah,  "filters"  makes me not see the new copying file.